# reading crash/memory dumps on Windows XP

Tags: c#, wpf, debugging, windows-xp

I have coded a WPF application with complex video and trans coding features, using a couple of third-party DLLs.

It works fine in Windows 7 but when I try to run it on Windows XP, it crashes. I use a VMWARE station to simulate Windows XP as my test system.

What is the best way to check the crash reason?

What tools can read the crash report?

Comment: Well, for a start you should get hold of the error message that comes with the crash!

Comment: It's windows XP it only gives you a  send / don't send dialog

Comment: FYI to get the path to the crashdump generated by Dr. Watson under XP, run drwtsn32.exe from system32. You can also change the kind of crashdump created there too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually you would use WinDbg/NTSD/CDB in Debugging Tools for Windows to read the crashdump, but to get the managed portion of the stack from you'd have to .load sos.dll and use its commands. VS2010 with it's .NET 4.0 added support for mixed-mode dump debugging which is even better. Just open the crashdump in VS2010 as a project.

Answer (score 1):

Run the program in Visual Studio under Debug mode. If the program crashes, you'll see at which line of code the program crashed.. That should give you a starting point at diagnosing the problem.

Comment: For that I need to install VS2010 in the XP machine, this was my initial idea,I wanted to avoid it to save time.

Comment: No you don't, in the Windows directory you will find a .mdmp file, you can open this in WinDbg (or use remote debugging)

Answer (score 0):

VMware's video driver may not support the features you are trying to use.  Check VMware documentation.  You should also consult the vmware.log files in your host's virtual machine directory.

Comment: I use simple features, It also crushes in a real XP machine, I just for development purposes installed it inside VMWARE

Answer (score 0):

Did you check your Application EventLog?  (Start...Run... eventviewer.msc)  Sometimes the ".NET Runtime 2.0 Error Reporting" source will write something interesting.